# Firebase No Firebase App [DEFAULT]

Tags: node.js, firebase

Ok, so I am doing this in Nodejs:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
    apiKey: "...............",
    authDomain: ".................",
    databaseURL: "...........",
    projectId: "..............",
    storageBucket: ".",
};
```

but I am getting this error:

> [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

By the way, I have looked on the other questions, and they are all Typescript / front end js, this is Node.js

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Comment: Try to `deploy` the app again, it happens to me sometimes on slow network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use firebase admin sdk for nodejs. Firebase Javascript is for front end

Use this tutorial to set your admin sdk on your nodejs server : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. And followed few post on SO. Don't you think the admin setup is for dedicated servers ?

Comment: Yes it is for dedicated servers, not for front end applications. Admin sdk gives unrestricted access so should be used from backend server. If you need the functionalities you should create api which front end can call to do function. Make sure to put authorization on these api.

Comment: So is it only for dedicated servers ? Can I make my pc into server using http-server on nodejs and then use firebase admin ?

Comment: Basically I am running my application on nodejs and trying to use the firebase database. What will be the best approach for me to get it done through my pc ?

Comment: In your node server use admin sdk to access database. Call the node server api from you client via http request.

Comment: Can you provide me few example on this one ? how via http request ? I am running it on local

Comment: do yo know how to make a http rest api request to node server ?

Comment: I am using webpack-dev-server

Comment: If you can guide me in a proper direction how to do that and how should I set up my environment, would be a great help for me. I am new to node js. I was java and php developer. so it's bit confusing

Comment: for creating node server: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2

Comment: for adding firebase adminsdk to node server: https://hackernoon.com/nodejs-setup-firebase-in-4-step-tutorial-example-easy-beginner-service-account-key-json-node-server-d61e803d6cc8